# Remove trial version and JasperServer

Tags: jasperserver

I installed the trial version of JasperReports and created several reports and did not notice that soon expire the trial license .
I wonder if there is any way to remove the trial license and pass this version will be FREE free license without losing my reports .

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
A custom install will ask you if you want a new DB or use/update existing
   Point it to the trial vs. DB and finish with defaults.( change ports if you want to be running both apps with the same db)

You may nees to clean up what version of the app is in your tomcat apps

Option 2:
If you can still log into the trial ver.  Then login as superuser,  manage server, export 
On free version. Log into free version as superuser, manage server,import